# VS Code always starting in administrator mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running VSCode 1.31.1 on Win 10. I recently noticed that it is always starting in administrator mode, and I do not know how to run it without elevated privileges.

My user is not part of the administrator group, and other programs do not start in elevated mode.
I use WSL as a shell within VSCode, and running elevated causes problems because WSL cannot run both elevated(in VSCode) and non-elevated(outside of VSCode) at the same time

I already tried the following:

- I have checked the [shortcut](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/sites/default/files/gdrive/win_run_admin/run_admin_18.png) and [executable](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/sites/default/files/gdrive/win_run_admin/run_admin_17.png) properties, making sure "Run As Admin" is not set.
- I have removed all VSCode extensions
- I have reinstalled VSCode, trying both the User and System installer

Any idea what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Yes. Very weird behaviour. Am facing this issue as well